# ZF3 zend-cache error Unable to resolve service "FilesystemCache" to a factory

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-cache

I'm trying to use zend-cache with zend-rbac.

zend-rbac is ok, but when I try to add zend-cache I got this message:

> Unable to resolve service "FilesystemCache" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

My cache configuration at global.php is like this:

```
// Cache configuration.
'caches' => [
    'FilesystemCache' => [
        'adapter' => [
            'name'    => Filesystem::class,
            'options' => [
                // Store cached data in this directory.
                'cache_dir' => './data/cache',
                // Store cached data for 1 hour.
                'ttl' => 60*60*1
            ],
        ],
        'plugins' => [
            [
                'name' => 'serializer',
                'options' => [                        
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

And in my RbacManagerFactory I'm calling it like this:

```
$cache = $container->get('FilesystemCache');
```

I already try to config FilesystemService in my module, like this:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\FilesystemService::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

But it didn't work

Do I need to config something more?

**EDIT 2018-10-29**

When I try to run the [sample](https://github.com/olegkrivtsov/using-zf3-book-samples/tree/master/userdemo%22sample%22) it gives this error:

```
[Mon Oct 29 12:06:13.097747 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 943] [client 127.0.0.1:48824] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/roledemo/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/AbstractListener.php on line 65
[Mon Oct 29 12:06:13.098593 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 943] [client 127.0.0.1:48824] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(data/cache/module-classmap-cache.application.module.cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/roledemo/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/AbstractListener.php on line 65
[Mon Oct 29 12:06:13.112886 2018] [php7:error] [pid 943] [client 127.0.0.1:48824] PHP Fatal error:  Method Zend\\View\\Helper\\HeadTitle::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Zend\\I18n\\Exception\\ExtensionNotLoadedException: Zend\\I18n\\Translator component requires the intl PHP extension in /var/www/html/roledemo/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml on line 0
```

and I can't access any URL.

Could it be my php or apache version?

Comment: Set that up myself just recently. Guessing you've been doing [this](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Role_Based_Access_Control/Implementing_RbacManager.html) ? Have you made sure you've installed `zendframework/zend-cache` and `zendframework/zend-serializer`? I tried the same and it worked out of the box for me.

Comment: @rkeet Yeah, that's the tutorial I'm following.
I already install zendframework/zend-cache and zendframework/zend-serializer.
What's your php version?
It's still not working here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was missing some things, that's why it didn't work before:

- Create `data/cache` folder and give it permission 775
- Create `public/img/captcha` folder and give it permission 775
- Add module `Zend\Serializer` and `Zend\Cache` to `config/modules.config.php`
- Add the following to `module/Login/config/module.config.php`:

```
    'rbac_manager' => [
        'assertions' => [Service\RbacAssertionManager::class],
    ],
```

- And, if you are following the text, not downloading the code:
  Set `$result` as `false` in `src/Service/RbacManager.php` line 72